# Added tag on edit is already visible before edit is reviewed and approved

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, suggested-edits

When I review a person's question, remove an irrelevant tag and then add a relevant one, the added tag remains visible on the question once I've clicked 'Save Edits' and the removed tag has disappeared.

Of course you'd want this, but only after the edit was approved.

The tags on the right remain as they were (in the 'tagged' section).

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the thing that says something like "this edit will only be visible to you until approved"?

Comment: @PeterJ Yeah, sorry, my bad. Thought it reverted the text but not the tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your suggested edit appears to you as a done deal, though there is a banner that tells you that the changes will appear to others only after the edit is approved.

This has been done so people won't think that their suggestion disappeared completely and try it again.